# Exterior powers of a module contained in a field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am working some problems that can potentially be on a qualifying exam about tensor algebras and have come across some questions about field of fractions which is something I have not seen for a while and so I have not really been able to work through all the appropriate definitions to arrive at the correct proof.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $I$ be an integral domain and let $Frac(I)$ denote its field of fractions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions.

let $\wedge^k M$ be the $k$-th exterior power of $M$ that is $T^k(V)/A^k(V)$ where $A(M)$ is the ideal generated by all $m \otimes m$ for $m \in M$ and $T^k(M) = M \otimes M \otimes \ldots \otimes M$ is tensor product of $k$ modules.

Consider an $I$-module $M \subset Frac(I)$.

> How do we show $\wedge^k M$ is a torsion module for $k \geq 2$?

I think it is clear that the exterior power should be zero for $k <2$ but I am still not sure this is trivial after putting all the definitions together.

Comment: If M = Frac(I) is a one-dimensional vector space, then the 0th and 1st exterior powers of M are isomorphic to M, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let *K* be the field of fractions of the integral domain *I*, and let *I* ≤ *M* ≤ *K*.  Since tensor product is associative, *K* ⊗ ⋀(*M*) = ⋀(*K* ⊗ *M*) = ⋀(*K*) = *K* ⊕ *K*, which is zero for *k* ≥ 2.

An *I*-module *N* such that *K* ⊗ *N* = 0 is (by definition in some areas) a torsion *I*-module.  If *in* = 0 and *i* ≠ 0, then 1 ⊗ *n* = 1/*i* ⊗ *in* = 0.  The other inclusion follows from the flatness of *K*.

Comment: Could you explain the first two lines of this answer, please?